# Use Storybook server on AWS C9?

Tags: amazon-web-services, storybook, aws-cloud9

I'm trying to run a [storybook](https://storybook.js.org/) server on AWS Cloud9 but the URL it gives doesn't load anything.

I'm starting the server with

```
start-storybook -h $HOST -p $PORT --ci
```

This runs through without error and gives me a "server started" message with a URL. But that URL doesn't connect to anything.

I do notice that the URL isn't secure, and I can imagine AWS having issue with that. There is an `--https` option on the `start-storybook` command, but it requires SSL information that I don't know how to source.

Anyone know how this I can get this working?

Answer (score 0):

C9 only opens port 8080, 8081, 8082. So your server should be listening on one of three. Try:

```
start-storybook -p 8080 s public
```